# Using {{}} inside {% if %} in jinja

Tags: html, django, jinja2

```
{% for category in categories %}
            {% if request.get_full_path == '/?category={{category.0}}' %}
            {{ category.0 }}
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              <a class="nav-link" href="/?category={{ category.0 }}">{{ category.1 }}</a>
            </li>
            {% else %}
            {{request.get_full_path}}
             /?category={{category.0}}
            <li class="nav-item">
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              <a class="nav-link" href="/?category={{ category.0 }}">{{ category.1 }}</a>
            </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

I want to highlight navigation buttons, but {% if %} statement can't see {{category.0}} expression inside.

Can I use {{}} inside {% if %} statement in jinja?

Comment: `'/?category=' ~ category.0`

Answer (score 0):

No you can use your return variable in {% if %}
Without {{}}